# what is the easiest way for email notifications in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, notifications

I have simple ruby on rails app and I need some notifications system on admin email in rake ? What is the easiest way to do it?

Should I configure mail server on my vps for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action Mailer does the job ([guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3)).